# JavaScript loop with awaits doesnt exit when I want it to

Tags: javascript

I have this Promise map loop within another:

```
try {
    await Promise.all(
      projects.map(async (project: any) => {
        await Promise.all(
          project.members.map(async (user: UserInterface) => {
            await sendEmail();
            console.log('created email')
            emailsCreated++;

            if (emailsCreated === limit) {
              throw new AbortError('Limit reached');
            }
          }),
        );
      }),
    );
  } catch (_error: any) {
    if (!(_error instanceof AbortError)) {
      throw _error; // Rethrow if it's not the error we're expecting
    }
  }
```

The idea is that I go through all projects and all members and send emails to them. If the limit is reached i throw an Error to exit.

However I notice that mails are still sent even though i threw the error. Its like it still processes all items.

How could I do this properly?

Comment: All your promises start executing at the same time (at instantiation), so there's no way to end these, really, because they are all doing their thing and aren't connected. Maybe best to change `emailsCreated > limit` and move `await sendEmail` to inside the `if` to ensure you only send up to the limits of emails.

Comment: As the individual Promise objects resolve on the way to the point at which email is sent, those will proceed. As soon as you *start* an async operation, the wheels start turning.

Comment: And yea, you can count how many projects and members there are before you even start the process; that would not even be asynchronous.

Comment: Are there no NPM packages or so that solve this? Or nicer solutions?

Comment: You just need to do this in two steps: collect all your users, then send out the emails to all users or the maximum amount you are allowed to send out. There are no packages for this 'general' problem you are having, you will have to put it together with the core stuff you have.

Comment: An NPM package to count the members? I doubt it. The code for it would be `projects.map(p => p.members).reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0)` Doesn't need a whole package.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with an error which is strange, just get the needed number of users and send emails to them:

```
await Promise.all(projects.flatMap(project => project.members).slice(0, limit).map(user => sendEmail(user)));
```

You could shuffle users so not the same users would be bombed with emails every time (though you should use a db table to keep track of the users and shuffle them globally):

```
await Promise.all(projects.flatMap(project => project.members).map((item, i, arr) => {
    const idx = i + Math.random() * (arr.length - i) | 0;
    const val = arr[idx];
    arr[idx] = item;
    return val;
}).slice(0, limit).map(user => sendEmail(user)));
```